How to Automate Change Request in Azure DevOps Enterprise Server
In our organization, we currently use ProcessMaker for managing change requests and approvals, which involves uploading test scripts, results, and necessary documents for stakeholder and approver review. Once approved, the DevOps team can initiate deployment. However, this process is manual, and we aim to automate it by migrating change request management to Azure DevOps.
I have researched using gates in Azure DevOps to integrate with ServiceNow or external services, but I couldn't find any information on integrating with ProcessMaker. My questions are:

Can we fully migrate the change request process to Azure DevOps, where all necessary documents can be attached?

Is it possible to integrate ProcessMaker with Azure DevOps so that when a ProcessMaker case is approved, the pipeline automatically triggers the deployment?


Note: We use Azure DevOps Enterprise Server.
Looking for the best approach on how to get stared.

Generally speaking, the requirement is to automatically trigger Azure DevOps pipeline deployment upon the approval of the request in ProcessMarker.
There is no such built-in feature for Azure DevOps at the moment. As far as I tested, the process model with date connector could send WebHook payload to the Azure DevOps Services and succeeded in triggering the YAML pipeline in that organization by WebHook resource.

Webhooks were released in Azure DevOps Server 2020.1. However, for your scenario to use Azure DevOps server, it may not be possible, since the URL of your Azure DevOps Server may not be resolved by the data connector in ProcessMarker. Therefore, if you would like to use this workflow to trigger a YAML pipeline, you need to make sure the URL is resolvable by ProcessMarker, so that the WebHook request could be sent as expected. There is a chance that the Processmaker WebHook http request could be sent to the public IP of your Azure DevOps Server, but this could risk your server under exposure to public network.

Thanks Alvin. I guess we'll explore other options.
